# CheckBox helper keeps sending false value no matter what's the selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Here's my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddMCondition", "Admin"))
{
  <td class="admin-textbox">
      @Html.TextBox("txtMCondition")
  </td>
  <td>
     @foreach (var exerType in Model.AllExerciseTypes)
     {
      <label>
         @Html.CheckBox("RestrictedType")
         @exerType.Name
      </label>
     }
       <input type="submit" value="Add Medical Condition" />
     </td>
 }
```

and this is how I'm retrieving values in the controllers

```
public ActionResult AddMCondition(string txtMCondition, string[] RestrictedType)
{
   //Code here...
}
```

There are only 3 item in the **AllExerciseTypes** collections. I've notice that each checkbox is sending at least a **false** value to the controller whether it's selected or not. If I don't check any checkbox, I get 3 false in the collection. If I check 1 checkbox, I get 4 values, i.e. 1 true and 3 falses, and so on. When I check all of them, I get 3 values, i.e. True, False, True, False, True, and False.

Is there any reason, checkboxes are sending at least false in each situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Html Helper for a checkbox adds an extra hidden field with a value of false to ensure that something is posted back to the server even if the checkbox is not checked. If you add `<input type="checkbox" name="cbSomething" value="true"/>` to your form and post it back without checking the checkbox then you won't get a value sent back to the server. If you use the strongly typed helper extension (`Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RestrictedType)` for example) and bind a checkbox to a property on your model, the model binder will correctly bind the value to the model property. Here's the code snippet from the input extensions within MVC:

```
  if (inputType != InputType.CheckBox)
    return TagBuilderExtensions.ToMvcHtmlString(tagBuilder1, TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  stringBuilder.Append(tagBuilder1.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
  TagBuilder tagBuilder2 = new TagBuilder("input");
  tagBuilder2.MergeAttribute("type", HtmlHelper.GetInputTypeString(InputType.Hidden));
  tagBuilder2.MergeAttribute("name", fullHtmlFieldName);
  tagBuilder2.MergeAttribute("value", "false");
  stringBuilder.Append(tagBuilder2.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(((object) stringBuilder).ToString());
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand. I need to add value="true"? How about when I don't check a checkbox? its value will still be true at the controller level?

Comment: No, that was just an arbitrary value. If you don't check a checkbox, a value of false will be posted back to the server with the name of that checkbox (due to the hidden field). If you check the checkbox, the value you explicitly set for the checkbox will be posted back as well (usually true since we tend to use checkboxes as boolean). If you're using model binding, the binder will know whether to set your model property to true or false based on whether the checkbox is checked, even though there are 2 values sent back.

Comment: I can't use the model because it is huge and there are more forms in the entire page. Maybe I need just to implement the logic myself, i.e. found out the pattern of false and trues.

Comment: Worst comes to the worst you can pass `FormCollection` as an extra parameter and grab the values from there matching on name. If you have 2 for a specific name the checkbox has been checked (test the values to be doubly certain). If you only have one it's the default hidden field value only. Not very clean but better than going through a list of booleans

Comment: Thanks. Using FormCollection was a nice short-cut.